# awk based solution for summing the rows of multiple files

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have several files which look like

file1.dat:

```
1 1
1 3 4
5 9 10 11
```

file2.dat:

```
3 0
8 9 0
3 9 2 4
```

typically with many more rows (with each row containing one less column than the previous row). I devised a hybrid bash/awk script to sum the rows of each file, e.g. using the above as an example:

out.dat:

```
4 1
9 12 4
8 18 12 15
```

The script works as expected but is quite slow. Well over 30 minutes for 100 files each with 10000 rows on my machine. The script seems to spend most of the time collecting the nth row from all the files. Is there a way to perform my operation simply by passing `file*.dat` to the awk command (see below)?

```
#!/bin/bash
ROWS=$1; shift
OUT_FILE=$1; shift
IN_FILE=("$@")

for i in `seq 1 1 ${ROWS}`; do
    # Get ith row from all input files
    for j in "${IN_FILE[@]}"; do
        tail -n+${i} ${j} | head -1 >> "temp.dat"
    done
    # Sum the rows 
    awk '{for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) a[j]+=$j} END {for (j in a) printf a[j] " "}' temp.dat >> ${OUT_FILE}
    echo >> ${OUT_FILE}
    rm temp.dat
done
```

Script usage based on the above example: `./RowSums.sh 3 out.dat file*.dat`

Comment: Why is the second row of the output `9 12 0`? Shouldn't it be `9 12 4`? Do all files have the same number of rows?

Comment: Yes `9 12 4`. And yes the dimensions of all the files are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following awk script can pretty much replace the whole shell script:

```c
# cat rowsum.awk
FNR <= rows {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        sum[FNR,i] += $i
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= rows + 1; j++) {
            printf "%s ", sum[i, j]
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
}
```

Example:

```
% awk -f rowsum.awk -v rows=2 file*.dat
4 1
9 12 4
% awk -f rowsum.awk -v rows=3 file*.dat
4 1
9 12 4
8 18 12 15
```

This should be faster than going through all files again and again for each row.

Note: I'm assuming the *n*th row has *n+1* columns. If not, save the number of columns for each row (e.g., `cols[FNR]=NF`) and use that in the final loop.

---

Another, more memory-efficient option could be to use `paste` to get all the relevant lines from each file together:

```
% paste -d '\n' file*.dat                                                                                                                                                
1 1
3 0
1 3 4
8 9 0
5 9 10 11
3 9 2 4
```

And then use `awk` on them:

```c
# cat rowsum-paste.awk
NR > 1 && NF != prevNF {
    for (i = 1; i <= prevNF; i++) {
        printf "%s ", sum[i];
        sum[i] = 0
    };
    printf "\n"
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        sum[i] += $i;
    prevNF = NF
}
```

```
% (paste -d '\n' file*.dat; echo) | awk -f rowsum-paste.awk
4 1 
9 12 4 
8 18 12 15
```

This awk code sums lines until the number of fields changes, and then prints and resets the current sums. The extra `echo` is to change the number of fields at the end and trigger the final print, which can also be done with the printing code duplicated in an `END` block.

Comment: You could probably use `rows == "" || FNR <= rows` as the first condition, or remove it completely. I'm assuming that the `ROWS` variable in their code is a byproduct of their way of thinking about the problem rather than a necessary part of the solution.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes I've removed it. The script should have set `ROWS=$(wc -l)` or something.

Comment: @muru Thanks! Definitely faster than my script, at the cost of quite a bit of memory, which is fine. I hadn't realised that every line of the files supplied is looped over implicitly. Would it be faster / less memory expensive to print each line as you go? e.g. instead of `sum[FNR,i]` it is just `sum[i]`, print the line and repeat.

Comment: @algae Since all the fields on each line have to be summed with the corresponding elements in the other files, you can't really print each line as you go, as the sum would not be "done" yet.  Also, the amount of memory taken should be no more than the amount needed to store one of the files in RAM.

Comment: @Kusalananda Then I don't understand how the first for loop works. `arr[NFR,i]` points to the `FNR`th row and the `i`th column of all the `file*.dat`? After each FNR increment occurs you have a line ready to print. Though this would require another loop and not be worth it I guess

Comment: @algae `FNR` is the line number in the current file. The fields of that line has to be added to the corresponding entries in each of the other files.  When `FNR` increments, that just means you have started working on the next line from _the same file_.

Comment: @algae I added an alternative that should use much less memory

Comment: Yes! This is what I had in mind. Just couldn't see past the awk. It is also the fastest of all 4 solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Using any `paste` and any `awk`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

paste "${@}" |
awk -v numFiles="$#" '{
    numFldsPerFile = NF / numFiles
    for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numFldsPerFile; outFldNr++ ) {
        sum = 0
        for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++ ) {
            inFldNr = outFldNr + (fileNr - 1) * numFldsPerFile
            sum += $inFldNr
        }
        printf "%d%s", sum, (outFldNr<numFldsPerFile ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file1.dat file2.dat
4 1
9 12 4
8 18 12 15
```

Hopefully the descriptive variable names and explicit `inFldNr` calculation make it clear what that's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` to output a tab-delimited data set consisting of the row and column indexes in the first two fields, and the data value at that position as the third field, for all files:

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print FNR, i, $i }' file*.dat
```

Sorting the data and using GNU `datamash` to do a `crosstab` operation on the above-generated data, summing the elements that occur at the same (row,column) index (the `--filler ''` option makes `datamash` output nothing in place of `N/A` for missing fields):

```bsh
sort -n | datamash --filler '' crosstab 1,2 sum 3
```

Trimming off the added header on each column, and the initial column with the line numbers that `datamash` outputs:

```bsh
tail -n +2 | cut -f 2-
```

All together with the output, given the two files in the question:

```bsh
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print FNR, i, $i }' file*.dat | sort -n | datamash --filler '' crosstab 1,2 sum 3 | tail -n +2 | cut -f 2-
4       1
9       12      4
8       18      12      15
```

Benchmarking this and comparing it to [the solution by muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701220/116858), it is not quite four times slower (3.7) on the two tiny data files.

Comment: Nice. `datamash` requires tab delimited files? Why the tab

Comment: @algae It _assumes_ tab-delimited input, but you can use any delimiter and tell it what to use with other options. Tabs are nice because it's also the default delimiter for other tools, such as `cut`.  Tabs are false _whitespaces_, so any tool, such as `sort`, would be able to use them with no issue.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because initially, changing `'\t'` to `' '` didn't work. Good to know about tab default with these tools. Never really seen tabs used for data files.